# How to do some clean when class object is called?

Tags: python

Now I have a class to save kwargs as dictionary. Here is my code.

```
class A:

  def __init__(self):
    self.dict = {}

  def __call__(self, **kwargs):
    self.dict = kwargs
    return self

  def get(self):
    return self.dict

a = A()
print(a(i=1, j=2).get())
print(a.get())
```

The `a.dict` will be reset when `a()` is called. How can I do the same thing when `a` is called without parentheses? So the last line `a.get()` will return `{}` instead of `{i: 1, j: 2}`.

Comment: First, you can't do that. Second, this doesn't make any sense as a class - it doesn't sound like you actually want any persistent state. You should just build dicts the normal way.

Comment: " I have a class to save kwargs as dictionary." this really makes no sense... there is *already* a class for that... `dict`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always return a proxy object instead of the `A` instance to get the syntax you want.

```
class A:

  def __call__(self, **kwargs):
    return B(kwargs)

  def get(self):
    return {}

class B:

    def __init__(self, d):
        self.d = d

    def get(self):
        return self.d

a = A()
print(a(i=1, j=2).get())
print(a.get())
```